# Let $x$,$y$ be rationals such that $\frac{x^2+x+\sqrt{2}}{y^2+y+\sqrt{2}}$ is also rational, prove that either =, or +=−1.

Tags: proof-writing, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I followed one convincing proof in this [related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1620177/let-a-b-be-rationals-and-x-irrational-show-that-if-fracxaxb-is-rationa) but I don't understand the assumption and conclusion.

The proof goes as follows:

> Let $r\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that
> $\frac{x²+x+\sqrt{2}}{y²+y+\sqrt{2}}=r$ and suppose that $\frac{x}{y}$ is a irreducible fraction. Then
> $$\frac{x²+x+\sqrt{2}}{y²+y+\sqrt{2}}=r\Leftrightarrow
> > x²+x+\sqrt{2}=(y²+y+\sqrt{2})r\Leftrightarrow
> > x²+x-y²r-yr=\sqrt{2}(r-1).$$ If $r\neq 1$ we have
> $\sqrt{2}=\frac{x²+x-y²r-yr}{r-1}\in\mathbb{Q}$, but this is absurd.
> So we get $r=1$ and $$x²+x+\sqrt{2}=y²+y+\sqrt{2}\Rightarrow
> > y(y+1)=x(x+1).$$ If $x=-1$, we have $y(y+1)=0$ and so $y=0=x+1$ or
> $y=x=-1$. If $x\neq -1$ we have $$x=y(\frac{y+1}{x+1}).$$ If $y=-1$,
> it is analogous. We can suppose that $y\neq -1$. If $y=0$, $x=0$.
> Suppose $-1\neq y\neq 0$. We have $$\frac{x}{y}=\frac{y+1}{x+1}.
> $$Since $\frac{x}{y}$ is irreducible, follows the last equality that $x=y$.

I have two questions:

- Is it valid to suppose that $\frac{x}{y}$ is an irreducible fraction? Wouldn't that ignore other values?
- How assuming $\frac{x}{y}$ is irreductible follows that $x$=$y$ for  $\frac{x}{y}=\frac{y+1}{x+1}$?

I am particularly interested in the first question as it conflicts with my developing rigour in Mathematics.

Comment: I would agree that you should confirm that the argument has not lost generality.  More broadly, I suggest first showing that $\frac {a+\sqrt 2}{b+\sqrt 2}\in \mathbb Q\implies a=b$ (assuming $a,b\in \mathbb Q$ of course) and then using this to solve the given problem.

Comment: From $r=1$ you get $$0=y^2+y-x^2-x=(y-x)(y+x)+y-x= (y-x)(y+x+1).$$

Comment: It looks wrong since the conclusion $x=y$ and $x/y$ is irreducible is only possible if $x=y=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not allowed to even consider $x$ and $y$ integers.

When you arrive at
$$
x(x+1)=y(y+1)
$$
you're almost done, because this can be rewritten as
$$
x^2-y^2+x-y=0
$$
hence
$$
(x-y)(x+y+1)=0
$$